# Wolfram Mathematica reads but closes stream feeds from Arduino Serial port after a few data sets

Tags: serial, matlab

This is a Wolfram Mathematica / Arduino serial feed problem , but I am posting here just in  for any suggestions on enhancing the Arduino code or the Mathematica notebook.  The original post is here [Mathematica Exchange post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3016653?p_p_auth=WBKgU8ah) and in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189884/plot-serial-data-from-arduino-with-time-date-problem?fbclid=IwAR1_vyhguoj-hQFDVAZwcEWXy0XQWzAHs8ZKAr_R3lfv2WcrCYhAebfYPzU)

The Arduino sketch monitor a sensor and returns a set of three intergers.

```
     #include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_AS726x.h"

//create the object
Adafruit_AS726x ams;

//buffer para leer valores en bruto  
uint16_t sensorValues[AS726x_NUM_CHANNELS];

//buffer para  guardar los valores calibrados( no esta siendo utilizado en este codigo)
//float calibratedValues[AS726x_NUM_CHANNELS];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  
  // inicializa el pin digital LED_BUILTIN como un output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  
  //inicia y permite la comunicacion con el sensor 
  if(!ams.begin()){
    Serial.println("could not connect to sensor! Please check your wiring.");
    while(1);
  }
}

void loop() {

  //lee la temperatura del sensor
  uint8_t temp = ams.readTemperature();
  
  //ams.drvOn(); // descomentar esto si quieres usar el led del sensor para hacer medidas
  ams.startMeasurement(); //begin a measurement
  
  //permite que el sensor lea la data cuando este disponible 
  bool rdy = false;
  while(!rdy){
    //delay(1000);
    rdy = ams.dataReady();
  }
  //ams.drvOff(); //descomentar esto si quieres usar el led del sensor para hacer medidas

  //lee los valores!
  ams.readRawValues(sensorValues);
  //ams.readCalibratedValues(calibratedValues);

   //Serial.print("{");
  //Serial.print("Temp: "); 
  //Serial.print(temp);
  //Serial.print(",");
  //Serial.print(" Violet: ");
  //Serial.print(sensorValues[AS726x_VIOLET]);
   //Serial.print(",");
  //Serial.print(" Blue: "); 
  Serial.print(sensorValues[AS726x_BLUE]);
   Serial.print(",");
  //Serial.print(" Green: "); 
  //Serial.print(sensorValues[AS726x_GREEN]);
   //Serial.print(",");
  //Serial.print(" Yellow: ");
   Serial.print(sensorValues[AS726x_YELLOW]);
    Serial.print(",");
  //Serial.print(" Orange: ");
  //Serial.print(sensorValues[AS726x_ORANGE]);
   //Serial.print(",");
  //Serial.print(" Red: "); 
  Serial.print(sensorValues[AS726x_RED]);
  //Serial.print("}");
   
  Serial.println();
  //Serial.println();
  delay(400);
```

The Mathematica notebooks is

```
dev = DeviceOpen["Serial", "COM3"]

parseData[{val1__, 44, val2__, 44, val3__}] := 
 ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@# & /@ {{val1}, {val2}, {val3}}
parseData[___] := Sequence[]
rawReadings = {}
task = SessionSubmit[
  ScheduledTask[
   AppendTo[rawReadings, 
    DeviceReadBuffer[dev, "ReadTerminator" -> 10]], {1, 100}, 
   "AutoRemove" -> True]]
test1 = parseData /@ rawReadings
ListLinePlot[Transpose[parseData /@ rawReadings], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic] // Dynamic
DeviceClose[dev]
```

But the Notebooks is not returning a dynamic feed of data from Arduino. It closes and not able to determine why.  It is suppose to stream a feed continously.
[image]

Comment: I think the outcommented code should be removed.

Comment: There is a whole class of [these connection problems on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing+arduino). [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216620/processing-missing-serial-data-from-arduino-using-readstringuntil). [Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707859/how-do-i-control-servos-using-processing-code-and-an-arduino-uno-board). Here too?

Comment: This thread has nothing to do with Processing , LabView or Matlab.  It applies to Wolfram Mathematica handle of Arduino serial port.  Can you explain how these contribute to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Jose! As I already mentioned in Mathematica SE, you need to remove the delay statements out of your code and additionally send the data to serial only if new data has arrived.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I posted a update in Mathematica Exchange with a revised code with you suggestions.   But so far no getting the dynamic stream to maintain continuously.